audio adjustement problem Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
On Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS My problem is that I can't adjust the volume. It's either at 100 or 0. I can modify the service volume (for example, if I'm watching a video on YouTube, I can increase or decrease the volume using the video slider), but not the system volume (i.e., when I use the audio function keys or the volume slider from the panel, I can only have the sound off or at maximum; I can't set intermediate levels).

use ''alsamixer'' command

even with alsamixer does not work. The speaker does not change volume, the headphone yes.

amixer -D default set Master 100% ;
